# how to toggle mongodb field value on a click

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on an e-commerce project. admin wants to  change the user status on a click I tried a way to update the status of the user

```
<td id="status" onclick="changeStatus('<%=user._id%>' , '<%=user.status%>')"></td> 

   async function changeStatus(id , status){
         try{
           const res = await fetch("/admin/customers" , {
               method:"POST",
               body:JSON.stringify({id , status}),
               headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"}
           })
           const data = await res.json()

           if(data.message.includes("success")){
               location.reload()
           }
         }
         catch(err){
           console.log(err)
         }
       }

and in my serverside  i tried update my status 
customer_status: async (req , res) => {
   let {id, status} = req.body
   try{
     const updateStatus = await User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:id} , {$set:{status:!status}} , {new:true})
     console.log(updateStatus)
     res.json({message:"success"})
   }
   catch(err){
     console.log(err)
   }
   
   
 },
```

It works for the first time for a user anyone can explain why it's not updating simontionously

Answer (score 0):

We should use [$not](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/not/) aggregation for toggling boolean:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: id}, { $set: { status: { $not: "$status" }}}, { new: true })
```

Also note that some value cannot be casted to true or false, eg empty string `''`. In this case we have to tell Mongo how to handle, below snippet is for mongoose:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Schema.Types.Boolean.convertToFalse.add('');
```

Comment: got a cast error : cast to boolean failed for value